# Possible interface types that may show up in "ip addr show"?

Tags: linux, networking, parsing

Consider the output of a typical `ip addr show` on Linux:

```
# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,10000> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOTRAILERS,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/n brd nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn scope global eth1
    inet6 nnnn::nnnn:nnnn:nnnn:nnnn/nn scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Look at the first field of the second line of each interface output: it says "link/loopback" for the loopback interface and "link/ether" for the physical NIC.

My question is: What OTHER values can I expect in this field? "link/bluetooth"? "link/ppp"? Is there an authoritative list for these link type strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to simply grab the source for [iproute](http://developer.osdl.org/dev/iproute2/download/iproute2-latest) an look at the file **[ll_types.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git;a=blob;f=lib/ll_types.c;h=9d75bd26032a766e3a863ada70062333f120bb43;hb=HEAD)**.

Here is an incomplete list.

```
ether eether ax25 pronet chaos ieee802 tr arcnet
atalk dlci atm metricom ieee1394 infiniband
slip cslip slip6 cslip6 rsrvd adapt rose x25
ppp hdlc ipip tunnel6 loopback ltalk fddi
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ARPHRD_* entries in /usr/include/net/if_arp.h. I can't find any documentation that explicitly says this is the canonical hardware list, but it's what libpcap uses to determine the data link type for an interface.